# Polymorphism and Parameters?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So I understand that due to polymorphism one is allowed to do: 
Superclass Apt = new Subclass(); 
But I was wondering in the case of:

```
Superclass Abc = new Subclass(); 
do(Abc);
void doThat(Superclass Abc)
   Abc.Ball();
```

So in the Abc.method call inside the method doThat, does this make a call to the Ball method of the Superclass or does it make a call to the Ball method of the Subclass (assuming that the subclass has overridden the Ball method). If it does make a call to the overridden Ball method of the Subclass, why can we just not make the method doThat be: void doThat(Subclass Abc) instead. Thanks for the help and I'll clarify more if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this make a call to the Ball method of the Superclass or does it make a call to the Ball method of the Subclass

The call `Abc.Ball()` will call the overriden method in the subclass.

> If it does make a call to the overridden Ball method of the Subclass, why can we just not make the method doThat be: void doThat(Subclass Abc) instead

Imagine you have two subclasses of `Superclass`:

```
Superclass abc = new SubclassA();
Superclass xyz = new SubclassZ();
```

Defining `void doThat(Superclass abc)` means that the method `doThat()` will accept any object that is an instance of `Superclass` or any of its subclasses. Then you could do `doThat(abc)` and `doThat(xyz)` and both would call the `Ball()` method in the appropriate instances.

In contrast, if you had `doThat(SubclassA abc)`, you would also need a specific method for each subclass of `Superclass`, like `doThat(SubclassZ xyz)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's calling the overridden method that's the method overriding is for.

```
void doThat(Subclass Abc)
```

if you use `Subclass` here you can only pass Subclass instance to this. Instead if you have

```
void doThat(Superclass Abc)
```

Then you can pass any object which implements `Superclass` That's where the polymorphism comes. `doThat` method accepts many type of objects, only requirement is it should implerments Superclass.

If I explained further,
Lets say you have two Subclass called, `Subclass1` and `Subclass2` and these are implementation of Superclass where the Superclass is an interface. (These Subclasses should implements Superclass method definitions, therefore  both subclasses has `ball` method)

Then whatever the instance come to the `doThat` method it calls the `ball` method of the corresponding object. As the `void doThat(Superclass Abc)` accept Superclass type.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Ball` method is static, it will call on super class as `Ball` method is defined at class level while if it's defined at object level, then definitely it will call overridden method on sub class.

Answer (score 0):

In the situation you describe, the call

```
Abc.Ball();
```

will call the implementation in `Subclass`.